# How to import xml files into Maple worksheet

Tags: xml, import, maple

I have found a bunch of maple worksheets on the internet. However, when you open them they are in XML format like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Worksheet>
<Version major="12" minor="2"/>
<Label-Scheme value="2" prefix=""/>
<View-Properties presentation="false"></View-Properties>
<MapleNet-Properties elisiondigitsbefore="100" labelling="true" indentamount="4" elisiontermsthreshold="10000" ansi="false" errorbreak="1" useclientjvm="true" echo="1" imaginaryunit="I" labelwidth="20" plotdriver="openviz" elisiondigitsafter="100" plotoutput="terminal" rtablesize="10" elisiontermsbefore="100" elisiondigitsthreshold="10000" typesetting="standard" plotdevice="inline" verboseproc="1" showassumed="1" errorcursor="false" longdelim="true" plotoptions="" quiet="false" elisiontermsafter="100" screenwidth="79" preplot="" prettyprint="3" displayprecision="-1" warnlevel="3" screenheight="25" latexwidth="6.0" postplot="" prompt="&gt; " ShowLabels="true"/>........
```

That is just part of a file I found. Anyway, how can I import files like these into Maple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save these with `.mw` as the filename extension then the Maple GUI (or its desktop icon) should be able to launch these as usual.

That XML format is basically how all .mw worksheets of Maple's Standard GUI are formed. The GUI knows how to open .mw files which were last saved in an earlier version.

When you write "open them" do you perhaps just mean clicking a URL in your web browser? If so, then it could just be that your browser isn't associating that filename extension with the Maple GUI.